# curl_init on Windows

Tags: php, curl, init

1. I am trying to run curl on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.
2. I have downloaded PHP from here: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-7.0-nts-VC14-x64
3. And curl from here: http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/
4. I have copied the development php.ini into the windows directory and uncommented the  ;extension=php_curl.dll line.
5. I have rebooted.

When I run my php script it fails. It appears that the curl_init is not working.
The code is:

```
    <?php
    $url = 'https://rest.tsheets.com/api/v1/jobcodes';
    $api_token ="******************";
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer {$api_token}";
    $ch = curl_init();
    echo $ch;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    $o = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "This is output: " . var_dump($o); 
?>
```

I am running this from the command line using `php -f filename.php`, the output is :

```
F:\BITS\Development\TSheets\PHP>php -f t.php
bool(false)
This is output:
```

The fact that the $ch variable is false suggests to me that the curl_init instruction isn't working. If I substitute another url I get the html back for the page but it is not in $o which is where the output is returned when I run the script on a web server.

I'm sure I've missed something in the setup!
All help appreciated,
Neil

Comment: This doesn't mean that you have broken curl. It means that request has error. check http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: I use MAMP, it's, in my opinion, better than wamp or xampp. However, with your curl_init, try passing your url into your init as curl_init($url) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks xAqweRx, I can at least see the error! No idea what :

Comment: Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificatebool(false) is the error message. I'll go and look it up!

Comment: I have Xampp loaded. How would I run a script from the command line using Xampp? Is there a console option?

Comment: OK, I put the cacert file in place and it now returns some data! Thanks guys - fantastic. The problem is it return the data to the screen insteadof putting it  in the variable. I'm using the line $o = curl_exec($ch); Why does it put the output on the screen instead of into the var (which is what the server version does). Is it a setting in php.ini?

Comment: Thanks Ray, that's really interesting. I think I have it working now and the added confusion of curl means I'll stick with it this way on this PC but I'll probably use Xampp on the other installation.